# How to use the apply function to find the mean of array entry in the same position in R

Tags: r, arrays, apply, mean

For the following array

```
z <- array(1:12, dim = c(2,2,3))
 z
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9   11
[2,]   10   12
```

I would like to construct a `2x2` matrix by taking the mean value of the same position entry. My first entry is the average of `1,5,9` and the second entry is the average of `3,7,11` the third entry is the average of  `2,6,10` and fourth entry is the average of `4,8,12`. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We specify the `MARGIN` as 1 and 2, and apply the `mean` using `apply`

```
apply(z, c(1,2), mean)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5    7
#[2,]    6    8
```

Or specify one MARGIN and use `rowMeans`

```
apply(z, 1, rowMeans)
```